# Tensorflow: analogue for numpy.take?

Tags: arrays, numpy, tensorflow

Is there analogue for `numpy.take`? 
I want to form `N+1`-dimensional array from `N`-dimensional array, more precisely from array with shape `(B, H, W, C)`  I want to make `(B, H, W, X, C)` array.

I suppose that for my case there is solution even without such general operation. But I'm really unsure that if I will write code with multiple intermediate operations and tensors (shifting, repeating and so on) TF will be able to optimize it and remove unnecessary operations. Moreover I suppose that such code will be unclean and just awful.

I want to add dimension with shifted values. I.e. for (H,W)->(H,W,3) dimensions case indices must be

```
[
[[0,0], #[0,-1], may be padding with zeros but for now pad with edge value
[0,0],
[0,1]],

[[0,0],
[0,1]
[0,2]]
...
[[1,0],
 [1,0],
 [1,1]],

 [[1,0],
 [1,1],
 [1,2]],
...
]
```

I thought about `tf.scatter_nd` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) but for now I don't understand how to use it. If I understand correctly, I can't use `indices` with shapes larger than shapes of `update` array (i.e. I can't use `indices` with shape `(3,4,5,3)` and `update` with shape `(3,4,3)` or even `(3,4,1,3)`. If it's so then this operation seems useless until I make intermediate array with shape that I need to form in result.

UPD: may be I'm wrong and tensors operations (shifting, tiling and so on) is more appropriate and efficient solution.
But in any case I think that analogue for `np.take` will be useful.

Comment: I don't understand your `np.take` analogy.  It's just indexing along one dimension - with the option of wrapping or clipping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest function in tensorflow to `np.take` are [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) and [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd).

`tf.gather_nd` is more general than `tf.gather` (and `np.take`) as it can slices through several dimensions at once.

A noticeable restriction of `tf.gather[_nd]` compared to `np.take` is that they slice through the first dimensions of the tensor only -- you can't slice through inner dimensions. When you want to slice through an arbitrary dimension (as in your case), you need to transpose the array to put the slice dimensions first, gather, then transpose back.

Comment: Thanks!
I not sure that I understand statement about slicing. I just build full indexes without slices (with numpy) and gather data using this index. Seems like it works, at least there are no errors from TF. Will try to test it.

Comment: Thanks, @P-Gn, I've encountered the same problem. And can't find any solution to slice the teensor through the inner dimensions indices. the transpose seems the only solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Exemplary code for `tf.gather` replacing `np.take`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5, 7, 42])
b = np.random.randint(0, 3, (2, 3, 4))
c = a[b]
result_numpy = np.take(a, b)

print(a, b, c, result_numpy)

import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
b = tf.convert_to_tensor(b)
# c = a[b] # does not work
result_tf = tf.gather(a, b)

print(a, b, result_tf)

assert(np.array_equal(result_numpy, result_tf.numpy()))
```